# Search result pager

Tags: 7, search

anyone knows how to print all results at search results page?? (no pager)
The default template, print a pager and i don't know where it came from

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) alongside any other module or you can control search result by views module using search api.

At the other hand, there is a function in search module:

```
pager_query("$select $sort_parameters", 10, 0, $count_select, $arguments);
```

And you could copy search module in custom directory (sites/all/modules/custom) and modify this line as you wish. So that your modifications will not be erased when you will try to update your core or modules.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. i'll copy search module to avoid re-make on updates. =)